# Editing wordpress theme with dashboard

Tags: wordpress

I created sample website in wordpress.I'm newbie.I want to edit it again.Now the website show without dashboard.how to bring back edit option to that wordpress theme.Now This shows only web page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are reffering to wordpress built in file editor. By default it is enabled, but if somehow it has been disabled you can enable it by going to wp-config.php and add this code to the top.

```
define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', false );
```

Comment: just paste this code in wp-config.php or if you already have this code in it, change it from true to false.

Comment: I pasted this code and refreshed my page.Still I didnt found editor

Comment: ya I do it in my local host.

Comment: No i ment are you logged in as administrator? It should work fine on local, did you mess about with the file permissions? What i would suggest is do a search for "DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT" on your complete website directory. It might be in your theme that you installed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71314/discussion-between-vani-and-omer-farooq).